# Menu for a turn based game

Tags: python, menu

Our teacher has assigned us an assignment for doing a turned based game.

This only included name.strip() but this does not prompt player to input unique name:

```
def start():
   
   print("\nNew game started...Setting up Player 1's team...\n")
  
   for total_characters in range (1,4):
       name = input('Enter a unique name for unit #'+str(total_characters)+'==> ')
       if not name.strip():
           print('Cant be blank name,please provide a unique name')
           return start()
       else:
           role_selection()

def role_selection():
   for total_characters in range (1):
       role = input('Select unit #'+str(total_characters)+' type: (W)arrior, (T)anker, or Wi(Z)ard ==> ')                        
       total_characters+=1
       if role.upper() == 'W':
           pass             
       elif role.upper() == 'T':
           pass       
       elif role.upper() == 'Z':
           pass
       else:
           print("I don't understand what are you typing.")
           return role_selection()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are things that doesn't make sense :

- You have the exact same function twice :

  `def set_up(team_size)`

  `def set_up(name)`
- You are doing :

```
    for total_units in range(team_size):
        [...]

        invalid = True

        [...]

        while invalid: # Infinite loop
            set_up() # What's this function ?
```

As you can see from the comments in the code above, you never set `invalid` to `False`, leading to the infinite loop.

**Note:** My recommendation is that you should check out some tutorial on python before moving on coding a complex project, because your homework is not that easy.

Edit :

From the new code you've posted, you could do something like this :

```
def new_game():
  names = []
  for unit_id in range(1,4):
    print(f'Enter a unique name for unit #{unit_id}  ->')
    empty = True                                            
    while empty:
      name = input('>')                                                              
      if name == "":
        continue
      empty = False
      if name in names:
        print('Unit name must be unique.')                                                                              
      else:
        print('Name looks good!')
        names.append(name)

  python menu
```

Comment: Hi, thank you @JoJo.
I have tried several ways and edit the post. 
I have set a few if/elif/else but if unit name # 2 same as unit name #1 it does not prompt `'Unit name must be unique.'` Not sure what is wrong here..

Comment: In your last edit, you are setting `repeated = False` at the start of each loop `for set_up in range(1,4)`, so you'll never validate the `if repeated` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have edit to return back to `new_game()` if the name is not unique or blank. Is this code too long for player to input from unit #1 name again?

Comment: It'll more likely end up as a mess. Split your code in more precise and functionnal function if needed, and use the new_game function when you start a new game only.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this stood out to me:

```
    if not name.strip():
        print('Unit name could not be blank.')
    invalid = True
```

Remember in python the indentation matters. You are setting invalid to True regardless of the if condition. Further down you have a while loop that checks it.

The other if conditions have `invalid=True` inside the condition. Plus you don't have `invalid=False` anywhere as far as I see, so you'll get an error if you don't declare it somewhere so it's always on the path before the while.

Comment: Thank you Carlos.
I have tried several ways and edited the post. 
I have set a few if/elif/else but if unit name # 2 same as unit name #1 it does not prompt `'Unit name must be unique.'` Not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't seem like a specific problem, more an ask for general guidance for going about this kind of problem?

One thing to note is that your above script only uses functions (which store behaviour) whilst really for something like the turn based game, you need to store behaviour (attacks etc) and information (how much health is left etc).

I won't write the script for you, but here's an example of how you might define an rpg like entity, capable of attacking, being attacked by another entity etc:

```
class Entity:
"""Abstract class for any combat creature"""

def __init__(self, name, health):
    self.name = name
    self.health = health
    self.is_alive = True

def attack(self, other):
    dmg = random.randint(7, 12)
    other.be_attacked(dmg)

def be_attacked(self, dmg):
    self.health = self.health - dmg
    if self.health <= 0:
        self.die()

def die(self):
    self.is_alive = False

def check_life(self):
    return self.is_alive
```

You can then initialise a bunch of these to make up the 'team' you where talking about:

```
one_person = Entity('Lee', 34)
another_person = Entity('Someone Else', 21)
```

etc. Hope that helps a bit. Good luck with your project and have fun!

Comment: Thank you @houseofleft
very appreciate for your guidance. 
I'm totally new to python and may I know how to set python to detect duplicates input and prompt player to type a new name?
I have edit the post with another code, will it works?

Comment: Looking at the new code you've added, the main bit you might want to consider is the 'if name == '': continue' section. That looks like it'll trigger an endless loop, since there isn't an escape condition inside that loop. Instead you'd want to try something like: 'if name == "" or name in names: name = input('enter name:')' that way, it'll keep asking for a repeated input until it meets your conditions.